# Saving Multiple Entries of an Entity in MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am trying to have a view where I can update multiple entries of the same entity type simultaneously. The data all come from a I have the following setup, but it won't save the entries properly.

**View**

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.A>


@using (Html.BeginForm("update", "Default", "POST"))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>Headings</tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
        <tr>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i], "EditorTemplate")
        </tr>
        }
        </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.A

            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(new List<String> { "Open", "Resolved", "Cancelled" }, "Value"), Model.Status)
            </td>             
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Revised_Estimate, new { style = "width:5px" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Actual_Completion_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = Model.Actual_Completion_Date, @class = "form-control" } })
            </td>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult update(List<A> aList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count(); i++ )
    {
        A entry = aList.ElementAt(i);
        db.Save(entry);  // Built-in function to save each entry
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction();
}
```

Any pointers why this is not saving properly?

Comment: You should attach the entry to the context OR Use then Id to retrieve It from the DB and the assign each changed property.

Comment: It's all about the only thing you don't show: what happens in `db.Save`?

Comment: @GertArnold the db.Save is an imported function from the linked SQL database that saves the entry to the database. This function works when I were to save the entries one-by-one, but somehow fails in this case. Any pointers?

Comment: A function to save entries to the database??? That's bound to interfere with `SaveChanges`. Why do you need this method?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a class representing what you wrote as "A"

So if you try to enter list of "A" in your database, you should have a table that store "A" objects

So the code will probably be:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count(); i++ )
{
    A entry = aList.ElementAt(i);
    db.A.AddOrUpdate(entry);
    // Instead of using AddOrUpdate you can use Add function
    db.Add(entry);

}
int results = db.SaveChanges();
```